# How get ZurbFoundation 6.4.3 working in angular 4.4.4 project

Tags: javascript, css, angular, frameworks, zurb-foundation-6

I've been trying to get zurb 4.3 foundations installed with my angular 4 project. I followed the steps for this site I found.
https://shermandigital.com/blog/zurb-foundation-with-angular-cli/
but it's not working. can someone give me a step by step process to get the Zurb foundation framework to work with my angular 4 project? and please include all code needed for a test to run. Assume this is a brand new project made with the angular-cli.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What errors were you getting?

Comment: I got the errors to go away but when i try using the grid it doesn't work i also tried the accordion but when i click it to open the just jumps me to the top of the page. I get the feeling that the java script isn't working. also there are no errors in the browser console.

Comment: Have you included jquery and foundation.js scripts?

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd write up some updated steps since this post and this [link](https://shermandigital.com/blog/zurb-foundation-with-angular-cli/) are over a year old. With this in mind, the version of Angular is 6.1.10 and the version of Foundation is 6.5.0.

### Create new Angular CLI project & install dependencies

1. Create a new Angular CLI project with the SCSS style option:
   `ng new ng-foundation-app --style=scss`
2. Once installed, move into the `ng-foundation-app` directory:
   `cd ng-foundation-app`

#### Install Foundation for Sites

3. Install the SCSS version of the Foundation for Sites (At the time of writing v6.5.0) project with:
   `npm install foundation-sites --save`

*You might see a warning about installing missing dependencies. We will install jQuery next, and ignore what-input.js since it doesn't break anything in this guide.*

#### Install jQuery

4. Install jQuery since it is required by Foundation for Sites:
   `npm install jquery@2.2.0 --save`

### Configuration

5. In the `src/assets/` directory, create a new directory named `foundation-sites`.
6. In this new directory paste a duplicate of:

   - `_global.scss` from: `node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/_global.scss`
   - `_settings.scss` from: `node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss`
7. In the duplicated `_settings.scss` and `_global.scss` files, find the line with @import 'util/util'; and change it to point to the proper directory: 
   `@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_util';`
8. In `src/styles.scss`, add the import statements from `node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss`, and adjust the directory paths. (Note that we are using our duplicated `_settings.scss` and `_global.scss` files that we placed in the `src/assets/foundation-sites` directory.
9. In this same file, include: 
   `@import "../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation";`

Your `src/styles.scss` file should look like this:

```js
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.5.0
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */

// Dependencies
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/vendor/normalize';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/helpers/missing-dependencies';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/helpers/true';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/contain';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/purge';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/remove';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/replace';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/to-list';

// Foundation base
@import "../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation";

// Settings (Custom)
@import 'assets/foundation-sites/settings';

// Global variables and styles (Custom)
@import 'assets/foundation-sites/global';

// --- Components ---
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/forms/forms';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/typography/typography';
// Grids
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/grid/grid';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/xy-grid/xy-grid';
// Generic components
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/button';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/button-group';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/close-button';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/label';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/progress-bar';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/slider';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/switch';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/table';
// Basic components
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/badge';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/breadcrumbs';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/callout';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/card';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/dropdown';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/pagination';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/tooltip';
// Containers
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/media-object';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/orbit';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/responsive-embed';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/tabs';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/thumbnail';
// Menu-based containers
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/menu';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/menu-icon';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion-menu';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/drilldown';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/dropdown-menu';
// Layout components
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/off-canvas';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/reveal';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/sticky';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/title-bar';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/top-bar';
// Helpers
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/float';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/flex';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/visibility';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/prototype/prototype';


@mixin foundation - everything(
  $flex: true,
  $prototype: false
) {
  @if $flex {
    $global - flexbox: true!global;
  }

  // Global styles
  @include foundation - global - styles;
  @include foundation - forms;
  @include foundation - typography;

  // Grids
  @if not $flex {
    @include foundation - grid;
  }
  @else {
    @if $xy - grid {
      @include foundation - xy - grid - classes;
    }
    @else {
      @include foundation - flex - grid;
    }
  }

  // Generic components
  @include foundation - button;
  @include foundation - button - group;
  @include foundation - close - button;
  @include foundation - label;
  @include foundation - progress - bar;
  @include foundation - slider;
  @include foundation -
    switch;
  @include foundation - table;
  // Basic components
  @include foundation - badge;
  @include foundation - breadcrumbs;
  @include foundation - callout;
  @include foundation - card;
  @include foundation - dropdown;
  @include foundation - pagination;
  @include foundation - tooltip;

  // Containers
  @include foundation - accordion;
  @include foundation - media - object;
  @include foundation - orbit;
  @include foundation - responsive - embed;
  @include foundation - tabs;
  @include foundation - thumbnail;
  // Menu-based containers
  @include foundation - menu;
  @include foundation - menu - icon;
  @include foundation - accordion - menu;
  @include foundation - drilldown - menu;
  @include foundation - dropdown - menu;

  // Layout components
  @include foundation - off - canvas;
  @include foundation - reveal;
  @include foundation - sticky;
  @include foundation - title - bar;
  @include foundation - top - bar;

  // Helpers
  @include foundation - float - classes;
  @if $flex {
    @include foundation - flex - classes;
  }
  @include foundation - visibility - classes;
  @if $prototype {
    @include foundation - prototype - classes;
  }
}
```

### Run the project

10. Run the project with the `ng serve` command. The Foundation for Sites styles should be applied to your HTML, which you can view by directing your browser to http://localhost:4200.

### Foundation CSS/JS example

File: `src/app/app.component.html`

In this file I have added a simple foundation grid and accordion.

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>

<h2>Foundation XY Grid</h2>

<div class="grid-container fluid">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-3">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-3">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-3">Cell</div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-3">Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Foundation Accordion</h2>
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      <p>Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <a href="#">Nowhere to Go</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      <textarea>I'm a textarea input...</textarea>
      <button class="button">I do nothing!</button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 3</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
      Type your name!
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

File: `src/app/app.component.ts`

In this file I have included jQuery and Foundation JS. Per the Foundation documentation we must include `$(document).foundation();`.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'foundation-sites';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  public ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).foundation();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Answer :)